# how to check what graphics driver is currently loaded

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

Okay, so nvidia and nouveau don't play well together and I'm currently trying to set up my system where I will have both installed and can choose which drivers to use at boot(by blacklisting the other). Currently I have quite a few settings in my `.bash_profile` that are specific to the nvidia drivers.

I was wondering how to tell what drivers are in *use*

Comment: What does this show. I have Intel and it shows the i915. `sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration` If proprietary driver install, this will show it: `dkms status` Mine is blank.

Comment: You might also try: `lspci -nnk | grep 0300 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: both commands do the job well enough without super user privileges, which is what I need because this is going to be checked at login in both admin and regular user accounts, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

lspci will list all devices and the model,
you can use "lspci | grep video" to narrow down displayed devices
sometimes you need to use VGA instead of video

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @chili555's comment I was able to get a start on explicitly matching just the driver name:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0300 -A3 | grep -oP "(?<=driver in use: ).*"
nvidia
```

Wrap this in an alias or just put the entire command in a conditional and I'll be able to set environment variable only if the Nvidia drivers are in use.